# What happens when a vampire in gaseous form in a narrow tunnel dies?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

We managed to trap a vampire in a narrow tunnel which he usually used for escaping. She wasn't aware that we blocked the other exit by wax, and our cleric turned her so she ran away to the corner and went into the little hole with the other end waxed. We came and waxed this end too so she got stuck.

Question is, what happens when we add enough holy water in the narrow tunnel so that she eventually dies? Does the vampire materialize? (there is no space enough for her body in the tunnel) What happens to the items she was wearing? Does she just turn into vampire dust with all her items?

Comment: 1.How are you adding water to the tunnel if the exits are all sealed?  2.How sure is your part that there's no 3rd exit?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. I thought that the whole we-trapped-a-vampire-in-a-too-small-space-while-it-was-in-gaseous-form question had already been at least discussed, but a cursory search turned up zilch, so good question, then. I must ask, though, how will the holy water be added to the narrow tunnel without also giving the vampire an opportunity to escape? Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: [*Teleport Object*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportObject.htm)?

Comment: the exits are sealed with wax. we were thinking injecting by a syringe or a funnel of sorts through the wax

Answer (score 4):

First, the vampire will lose its hit points and be forced into gaseous form (yes, it's already in gaseous form.  This doesn't actually matter).  Then it will die, not from holy water but because it is unable to reach its coffin, after two hours:

> A vampire heals 5 points of damage each round so long as it has at least 1 hit point. If reduced to 0 hit points in combat, it automatically assumes gaseous form and attempts to escape. It must reach its coffin home within 2 hours or be utterly destroyed. (It can travel up to nine miles in 2 hours.) Any additional damage dealt to a vampire forced into gaseous form has no effect.

However, as Holy Water deals either 1 or 2d4 damage and deals that damage *once*, not constantly, the vampire is unlikely to be significantly harmed unless you have a method of flushing the area with new holy water each round.  If you do, it's not the vulnerability to Holy Water that matters, just the vulnerability to water in general:

> immersing a vampire in running water robs it of one-third of its hit points each round until it is destroyed at the end of the third round of immersion.

Which results in a dead vampire real fast, instead of after 2+hours.

As for the gear, see: [What happens to vampire possessions when he's destroyed in mist form?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104332/what-happens-to-vampire-possessions-when-hes-destroyed-in-mist-form)
(the answer is unclear because Vampires can't actually use their Gaseous Form ability as written).